# Where/How are class members stored in asp net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
 namespace test
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           List<Sticker> stickers = new List<Sticker>();
           //code that gets data from database and fills the list

                 for(int i = 0; i<stickers.Count;i++)
                {
                     Panel1.Controls.Add(stickers[i]);
                }
        }
    }
    class Sticker : ImageButton
    {
        string StickerID { get; set; }
        string PlayerName { get; set; }
        DateTime Date { get; set; }
        Label l;
        public Sticker(string StickerID, string Extension, string PlayerName, DateTime Date,Label l)
        {
            //code for setting data
            base.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(Sticker_Click);
        }

        void Sticker_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            l.Text = StickerID;

        }
    }
}
```

When i click the ImageButtons it writes the StickerID, but how does it know which class instance belongs to a particular user and where is this data kept?

I checked Session and has zero entries in it, decoded clientside ViewState no data for the class is kept there either

Comment: There is no way for SO community to know how your site stores the data. Feel free to read/debug the code to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance variables are not persisted by the framework. They are discarded when the current request ends. You must persist them manually if you want to maintain state.

ASP.NET does not keep persistent in-memory state across requests. That is an anti-pattern.

Comment: What actually confuses me is when i click the ImageButtons i get the corresponding StickerID, I expect to get null or something uninitialized since im not keeping the class instance

Comment: You probably are initializing that variable in the same request. Or, are you using data binding? The framework can funnel state through the ViewState in that case.

Comment: Tested it , it seems like it keeps the data needed in ViewState, when i make requests with empty value(value=""), the Label stays untouched